# Создание игр для android

Tags: android, разработка-игр

Купил планшет) И сразу же захотелось замутить игру. Как создавать и прочее хотел бы узнать из вашего личного опыта.

Вопросы примерно следующие.

- Какой нужен софт и нужен ли?
- Где можно найти хороший мануал по
     движку?
- Где можно скачать исходники хотя бы
     для понятия основ?
- На чём тестировать?
- Информация о различии версий android?
- Прочие ваши рекомендации...

**Спасибо)**

Comment: фигасебе разгон =) установи екслипс для начала =)

Comment: Купил телефизор) И сразу же захотелось замутить какой нибудь телеканал =)

Comment: @Gorets я когда учил php, не спал по 72 часа) так что "осведомлен значит вооружен")

Comment: я когда учил php, не спал по 72 часа++++ :D

Comment: вообще то вопрос очень наивный что-ли, какой софт нужен? - любой, с которым умеешь работать, надо ФШ, екликс, джава. На чем тестировать - то что есть под руками, на том и тестируй =), а еще неплохо бы денег много, людей и времени =)

Comment: @Gorets речь идет конкретно о собственном интересе и новых знаниях, по этому подтягивать людей чтобы удовлетворить свой интерес я думаю глупо)

Из вашего комента я уже понимаю что нужно учить Java))

Comment: вот оно, про что я и говорю, размах у тебя большой, типа, сегодня сяду и все сделаю =)

Comment: @Palmervan, ты это, со сном поаккуратней. А то здоровье подорвешь, как работать дальше будешь?

Comment: @mikillskegg фанатичность уже прошла)))

Comment: >> я когда учил php, не спал по 72 часа

кошмары? понимаю, понимаю...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Из движков могу посоветовать: [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/), [LibGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) сойдут отлично для простой 2D игры. Cocos2d-Android-1 мне не понравился. Если интересно опишу отдельно почему. 
То что предложили выше - платные и очень навороченные, а тут есть много нюансов. Сомневаюсь, что стоит начинать с них особенно если нет опыта в геймдеве или точного плана, то игра взлетит и как самое главное.

Также, нужно учить OpenGL ES(подмножество OpenGL) и связанную с этим математику. Очень помогает для понимания.

Игры тестировать лучше на устройствах с сами популярными разрешениями. Сам столкнулся с такой проблемой не так давно. На эмулятор например придется ставить эмуляцию аксселерометра или еще что-то

Начать стоит с установки Eclipse + плагинов для Android от гугла и ваш друг это - [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/index.html) Там есть все необходимое для изучения основ и куча примеров приложений, хотя они так же есть и в установленном вами SDK(при условии, что была поставлена соответствующая галочка). Кроме того куча примеров можно найти в гугле.

Answer (score 5):

http://developer.android.com/

Рекомендую.

Answer (score 4):

Начни отсюда [отсюда](http://dajver.blogspot.com/2012/01/android-1-surfaceview.html) 
И можешь еще заглянуть [сюда](http://megadarja.blogspot.com/2009/03/android-1-surface.html)

Сам по этим урокам учился

Answer (score 2):

Если интересует конкретный игровой движок для очень крутых игр (а я чувствую что вы в этом профи), то рекомендую [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/) или [Unreal Engine](http://www.unrealengine.com/)

Comment: я бы хуже крайтековского постеснялся предложить =)

Comment: Unreal Engine? Он как бы коммерческий, очень дорого)