# Написание 3D-игры

Tags: разработка-игр, документация

Здравствуйте!

Я хочу научиться создавать 3D-игры на PC, но ничего об этом не знаю. Помогите, пожалуйста, что мне изучать? Какими программами это реализуется? Также буду рад ссылкам на статьи, мануалы и вообще информации любого рода.

P.S.
Сложность игры планирую наращивать поэтапно:

1. Перемещение по трехмерному уровню.
2. Добавление цели, до которой необходимо добраться.
3. Добавление на уровень движущихся объектов (платформы, лифты и т.д.), анимация движения.
4. Добавление кнопок, изменяющих положение объектов на уровне (открыть/закрыть дверь; поднять/опустить лифт и т.д.).
5. Добавление противников, наращивание AI.

Спасибо.

Comment: литературу по математике можете почитать для начала

Comment: Кроме базовых понятий по математике нужно иметь хотя бы базовые навыки объектно ориентированного программирования (ООП), и тогда может быть у Вас получится сделать оконную игру (на формах) с примитивной графикой (точнее вообще без графики). Что - то типа сапёра, или тренировки быстрого письма.

Comment: А зачем при написании *Сапера* ООП ? 

У Вас что, клетки поля будут жить какой-то жизнью, обмениваться данными в разных ситуациях, следовать некой стратегии и т.п. ?

Comment: Я борюсь с искушением добавить метку `[корованы]`.

Comment: @avp, согласен. сапера я могу написать и сейчас, хотя бы в том же PascalABC.Рандомно раскидать по клеткам мины и обрабатывать щелчки мышкой по ним - дело 15 минут. А то, чем я здесь интересуюсь в разы сложнее.

Comment: @Starling

- Попробуйте разложить на 15-20 подзадач то, что вы назвали *"Перемещением по трехмерному уровню",* то есть составьте список того, что необходимо сделать в процессе реализации этой задачи. А дальше уже можно будет что-то пообсуждать.

- Просто, грубо говоря, *"наращивать AI"* на форумах много кто умеет, а четко и лаконично разбить задачу на подзадачи - это практически искусство.

Comment: Сапёр - то, что первое в голову пришло

Comment: мне сосед 13-ти летний тоже как то задал такой вопрос.

Comment: "Я хочу научиться создавать 3D-игры" - Это пройдет, стоит только открыть книжку по программированию.

Comment: Скоро вы начнете радоваться тому, что "Hello World" наконец-то заработало или получилось сделать новый тип данных, а не тому, а не этому:

     Сложность игры планирую наращивать поэтапно:
Перемещение по трехмерному уровню.
Добавление цели, до которой необходимо добраться.
Добавление на уровень движущихся объектов (платформы, лифты и т.д.), анимация движения.
Добавление кнопок, изменяющих положение объектов на уровне (открыть/закрыть дверь; поднять/опустить лифт и т.д.).
Добавление противников, наращивание AI.

Comment: Мне кажется, что над этим вопросом не стоит смеяться. Да, писать 3D игру - это задача не для новичка, который не представляет, как это сделать, но вопрос, ИМХО, корректный и вежливый.

Comment: @Construct, спасибо
@Asen, я уже пробовал кодить на Basıc и PascalABC, и мне знакомо чувство, которое испытываешь, когда видишь свою программу в работе) Но все это слишком далеко от 3D игр
@AlexSilaev, когда-то я хотул научиться хакерству, но с тех пор, как ради этого начал изучать программирование, про хак и не вспоминаю)).

Comment: Похвальное рвение, мне кажется.
Все указанные требования я лично реализовал после полтора месяца изучения OpenGL по интернету. Использовал Visual Studio 2008 Prof. (C#) и стандартные библиотеки OpenGL. В инете МАССА рекомендаций, литературы и примеров. Глупо по-моему даже ссылки давать)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Если Вы являетесь новичком, безусловно, лучшим стартом будет являться книга:
"Программирование на С++", авторы: Дирк Хенкеманс, Марк Ли. Она рассчитана как раз для начинающих (не знакомых с С++ или любым другим ЯП), и нацелена прежде всего на разработку игровых приложений (один из авторов - работник BioWare).
С языком С++ при разработке игр вам рано или поздно придется столкнуться, как бы Вы не хотели этого избежать.
После этого старта логичным будет прочесть книги OpenGL или DirectX (любую). Неплохим выбором может стать подборка отсюда: [блог серьезной дамы](http://alenacpp.blogspot.com/2008/01/blog-post.html) , а дальше у Вас уже должен сформироваться свой взгляд на то, какой язык и технологии использовать в своей работе.
P.S.: не советую на начальном этапе упираться в мобильные приложения или сетевые игры.

Comment: Спасибо за отличный ответ. Хотел уточнить: почему не стоит на начальном этапе упираться в мобильные приложения или сетевые игры?

Comment: Просто для того, чтобы не углубляться в специфику платформы на начальном этапе. Первым делом необходимо понять базовые принципы проектирования игровых приложений, а также основы машинной графики. Да и за 3D сразу хвататься не стоит. Параллельно не стоит забывать про примеры (поищите игру Змейка на OpenGL - для начала самое оно).

Comment: Ясно, спасибо.

Answer (score 10):

Это можно делать разными путями:

1. Самый простой: взять игровой конструктор и в нём всё сделать. Конечно, программирование всё равно понадобится, но его будет на порядок меньше, чем написание того же самого на C++ без движка.
2. Самый сложный: Изучить какой-то достаточно быстрый язык(например C или C++). Это может быть очень скучно, потому что на начальном этапе обучения ты не сможешь создать даже нормальное окно, не говоря уже о том, чтобы что-то там нарисовать. Будет только текст в консоли. Создание окон, рисование, звук - это всё дело библиотек. Дальше, изучаешь OpenGL или Direct3D (для графики) и OpenAL, DirectSound или XAudio для звука. Всё это совмещаешь и пишешь игру. Вот только в таком случае будет огромное количество низкоуровневого кода, в котором можно запутаться. Его надо грамотно обернуть в классы, то есть по сути создать свой движок. Зато потом на этом движке можно будет делать игры.
3. Средний: Взять готовый движок. Для этого достаточно будет знать только язык программирования, для которого он предназначен. Звук и графику движок возьмёт на себя.

Лично я пошёл по второму пути. Хотя он и самый сложный, зато я теперь знаю, как всё работает изнутри. До игры пока так и не дошло - уже 2 года нахожусь на стадии создания движка. Но у меня скорее больше желания написать хороший движок, чем сделать игру.

Comment: Спасибо. Кстати, помимо графики, звука и AI движок выполняет еще какие-то функции? Возможно глупый вопрос, но я в этом деле новичок.

Comment: Например, физика. Хотя бы проверка столкновений в нормальном игровом движке должна быть.

Answer (score 6):

@Starling, уточните, что за игру вы хотите написать: для браузера, десктопную или для мобильных устройств?

Полезные темы:

- [Язык программирования для разработки игр.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/12634/)
- [Литература для создания серверной части игр](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/74002/)
- [Создание игр для android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/69726/)
- [Игровой движок для Android. С какого лучше начать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/85242/)

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю, что Вам сюда: http://unity3d.com/

Хотя, если Вы не знаете языков программирования, то сюда: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Answer (score 2):

Игры писать одному или создавать свой 3D-движок не только не актуально, но и слегка ненормально.

Есть куча движков, из которых уже можно делать игры. Я было заинтересовался Ogre3D.org (бесплатен, расширяем, кроссплатформен) но он мне не понравился, так как это скорее графическая библиотека и нужны большие знания С++ и этой библиотеки. Unity3D очень не плох, кроссплатформен, цена не высокая (для некоммерч. - бесплатен), но его на практике не пробовал. Unreal Engine SDK  (UDK) самый продвинутый, лицензия нормальная, базируется на очень дорогом игровом движке (работает на DirectX). Кроме того есть PureBasic, DarkBasic, Game studio, и много других специализированных студий и языков. Везде каждый из них при должном подходе не имеет ограничений ни аппаратных, ни каких других. Я бы на вашем месте выбрал Unity или UDK. На крайний случай GameStudio. Удачи!

Comment: >создавать свой 3D-движок не только не актуально, но и слегка ненормально.

 Зайди на gamedev.ru. Там практически все такие. Значит это нормально.

Comment: @GLmonster Если бы хотя бы треть из этих "нормальных" вместо создания "самого лучшего и супер-пупер вообще движка" присоединилась к любому `opensource` проекту, было бы намного лучше.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, это наврядли. Приток клиентуры с не к ночи помянутого форума сильно снизит среднюю вменяемость по больнице любого проекта.

Comment: >Если бы хотя бы треть из этих "нормальных" вместо создания "самого лучшего и супер-пупер вообще движка" присоединилась к любому opensource проекту, было бы намного лучше.

 Вряд ли случится. Например я уже никогда не брошу свой движок. Слишком много сил и времени на него потрачено. И мне кажется, что по архитектуре кода он получается лучше, чем у других. Только функционал ещё маленький.

Comment: @semenvx27 Ну про разработку игр в одиночку я с вами категорически не согласен. Главное начать. А люди подтянуться. В пример можно привести Notch.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы полный новичок, то можете попробовать DarkBASIC и BlitzBasic. Благо с ними в комплекте идет уйма примеров, на которых можно набивать руку.